# Sublime Text HTML-CSS-JS Prettify Removing Code

Tags: formatting, sublimetext3, prettify, exacttarget

HTML-CSS-JS Prettify is by far the best formatting plugin I have found for Sublime Text, but I work on HTML Emails being sent with ExactTarget.

ExactTarget's Amp script for variable emails uses the format `%%=v(@var)=%%` and when I run the HTML Prettify plugin it changes my code to `%=v(@var)=%`

Why is a format plugin changing my code and not just formatting it? What in my settings can I change to keep this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify sections of code for the plugin to ignore. From their repo:
https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify#ignoring-certain-blocks-of-code

Comment: I don't understand that section. What file do I put it in, what is the `var a = 1;` part doing in that block.

Comment: Would i Just need to put %%=v or do I need the whole `%%=v(@var)=%%` because it doesn't look like he is closing his example

Comment: The `var a = 1;` is just example code, you can ignore that. Essentially, place `/* beautify ignore:start */` and `/* beautify ignore:end */` around your code that uses the format `%%=v(@var)=%%` and Prettify will not touch that section in any way.

Comment: Okay, so I have to put that start and end part in my actual HTML, not a settings file. Is it possible to set it up in a settings file, because I'm not always the author of the original HTML (which is why the format is terrible) and those variables are also inside href's and alt tags, not always somewhere you can put comments.

Comment: In the same link, you can look at the "Using your own .jsbeautifyrc options" section. In the html section, there's an "unformatted" property that has a list of tags that Prettify will not reformat. <a> tags are already in there so your href's should be fine. You can create another .jsbeautifyrc and add the other tags that have the alt attribute. This might not be a great solution but I don't know another way to do this. I hope this helps!